Ubuntu does not see any wifi networks
Hello I am new to Linux so sorry if i don´t give enough information.
As stated above Ubuntu does not see any WiFi networks.
Current setup
Operating system: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Processor: Intel Core i7-9700*8
Kernel Version 6.8.0-35 Generic
Wifi usb Card:TP-Link Archer T2U Nano AC600
(btw i am using usb Teathering right now )
Output of nmcli d
DEVICE                   TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION         
enx16bc9e5cb18a          ethernet  connected               Wired connection 1 
lo                       loopback  connected (externally)  lo                 
wlx9ca2f4cbada4          wifi      disconnected            --                 
p2p-dev-wlx9ca2f4cbada4  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --                 
eno1                     ethernet  unavailable             --                 

output of nmcli general Status
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected  full          enabled  enabled  missing  enabled 

output of sudo lshw -c network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 00:d8:61:4e:e7:ef
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.8.0-35-generic firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:126 memory:a5400000-a541ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@1:8
       logical name: wlx9ca2f4cbada4
       serial: 9c:a2:f4:cb:ad:a4
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau driverversion=6.8.0-35-generic multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@1:9
       logical name: enx16bc9e5cb18a
       serial: 16:bc:9e:5c:b1:8a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.8.0-35-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.128.7 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
``

**and most importantly the output of nmcli d wifi list**

``

nmcli d wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 


what I have tried
Reinstalling The Drivers for the wifi card
Reinstalling Ubuntu
Restarting Network Manager
